# The source code from requests.get does not match the websites source code

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm attempting to build a bot to retrieve one specific value from https://matcherino.com/tournaments/17147/overview but using requests.get pulls up a source code that does not match the site. It appears to pull up the source code for a chat bot to talk with the creators of the site.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://matcherino.com')
r = s.get('https://matcherino.com/tournaments/17147/overview')
print(r.text)
```

Sorry for not saying this originally, but I am trying to scrape the prize pool amount from the website.

Comment: the requests.get is returning the same as the page source. however the page them makes a number of DOM changes to the html to actually present content. are the html parts you are inerested in loaded from javascript or ajax updates to the html? if so you wouldnt see these in the html you get back from requests as that will be before any html updates.

Comment: The problem might be because python requests won't execute javascript. Depending on how the frontend of this website was built (javascript heavy e.g. angular) the downloaded HTML won't match the what your browser displays to you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to scrap from the website?

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the source code of the page, you can see that the prize pool isnt there, so it's loaded dynamically by Javascript and its gonna be a little more complicated to retrieve the information

i have never tried that but it looks like u can find the solution here : https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-skills-web-scraping-javascript-using-python-97a29738353f

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to this and just genuinely didn't know where to go, but I got it working thanks to your link.